# Is there Faster way to REGEX a SortedList?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, linq

voGenderList is a sortedlist(Of string, string) that contains a list of 30,000 names (Unique Name, Gender). I want to see how many of the names in that list contains "henry" i.e ("henry", "henryette", "henryate", "ihenry") will all be matches, if they were in the list.

<strike>Dim matchlist As Dictionary(Of String, String) = voGenderList.Where(Function(i) New Regex(i.Key).IsMatch("henry")).ToDictionary(Function(i) i.Key, (Function(i) i.Value))</strike>

```
Dim namelist As List(Of String) 'Contains 35000 unique names
Dim matchlist As Dictionary(Of String, String)

For Each oItem In namelist 
        matchlist = voGenderList.Where(Function(i) oItem.IndexOf(i.Key) >= 0).ToDictionary(Function(i) i.Key, (Function(i) i.Value))
        'Do other stuff with the results of matchlist
Next
```

The above code work and has been replaced with suggestions below, it's much faster then regex match that's crossed out. - Looping the above code 35,000 times takes approximately 5 minutes, which is a great improvement.

.contains and .IndexOf is close to around the same speed with IndexOf edging out.

I'm happy with the results now, but if someone has another suggestion to further improve it, I'm listening.

Comment: Is this just the example, or are you actually using a regular expression just to find a substring?

Comment: It's an example, I for each a list of names, with replaces "Henry" in the statement above.

Comment: So are you just using regex to check if a string contains a substring, or are you using regex features such as character escapes, substitutions, character classes, that sort of thing?

Comment: you're creating a new regex instance for each item in voGenderList ; could be better to create it before (with regexOptions.Compiled). but you don't really need the regex at all you could do `Key.ToLower.Contains("henry")` or `Key.IndexOf("henry", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1`. One could even try to use `Like` operator (but needs Option Compare Text)

Comment: You could use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(i.Key,"henry",CompareOptions.IgnoreCase)>=0` instead of a regex.

Comment: @Sehnsucht Take a closer look... CultureInfo has a CompareInfo that has IndexOf.

Comment: @spender missed that bit reading too fast ^^  but that's roughtly the same as calling string.IndexOf (the good StringComparison) just an "indirection" more in your case

Comment: Looking into the SOUNDEX() concept - it can at least reduce the number of compares you need to do. You may get too many matches...

Comment: @spender You're right, I don't need the regex, I originally did. Then when I rethought my logic, i didn't rethink how I was comparing. I can't believe I missed that, I'm re-testing now the indexof and contains to see if it makes a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parallel approach is the way to go.
You have here m-keys in voGenderList and n-keys in namelist, so effectively n * m iterations and between iterations you do not have to share any state, so it is intrinsically parallel problem.

Please note, that voGenderList is transformed to voGenderArray() to further improve speed, as FOR cycle is always faster than enumerating collection with so many items many times over.

I presume, you have at least two cores, if not, it will run sequentially, and gain little speed up thanks for FOR cycle, instead enumerating. Should have a measurable impact on 35k items

I could not test the code, but it compiles. VB.Net is not my language, but please believe me, the concept is sound:). If any issues, I will repair...

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Collections.Concurrent

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        'Somewhere defined
        Dim voGenderList As SortedList(Of String, String)
        Dim namelist As List(Of String)
        voGenderList = New SortedList(Of String, String)
        namelist = New List(Of String)

        'ConcurrentDictionary allows concurrent update of dictionary,
        ' names are unique, but they have to be inserted into dictionary,
        ' here concurrently
        Dim matchlist As ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
        matchlist = New ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))


        'SortedList is fine, but creating enumerator over list and enumerating it again and again is bad, array is better and FOR is faster
        Dim voGenderArray() As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) = voGenderList.ToArray()

        'Paralle computing
        namelist.AsParallel().ForAll(Sub(match) ParallelPart(voGenderArray, matchlist, match))

        'do something with matchlist, sequentially, concurrently as you see fit:)


    End Sub

    Sub ParallelPart(ByRef voGenderArray() As KeyValuePair(Of String, String),
                     ByRef matchlist As ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String)),
                     ByRef match As String)
        If (voGenderArray Is Nothing) Or (voGenderArray.Length <= 0) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim dictionary As Dictionary(Of String, String) = Nothing
        Dim size As Integer = voGenderArray.Length
        For i As Integer = 0 To size - 1
            Dim kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) = voGenderArray(i)
            If match.IndexOf(kvp.Key) >= 0 Then
                If dictionary Is Nothing Then
                    dictionary = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
                End If
                dictionary.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
            End If
        Next

        If Not (dictionary Is Nothing) Then
            matchlist.TryAdd(match, dictionary)
        End If
    End Sub


End Module
```

Comment: This method is lightning fast - what was taking over 6 minutes is now taking under 1 minute. I must admit, it took me a little while to figure out how to implement it properly in my context. I almost gave up, thinking it was to complicated for me. Then I re-grouped and have it working. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Great, glad to help:)